# How to add "Open Powershell Here" to right click menu for a file, not just folder

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have managed to add "Open PowerShell Here" to the right click menu of a folder, but when trying to open a file within a folder the right click menu shows no "Open PowerShell Here" in Windows 10.

What must I write in Registry to fix this?

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  It has to open/run in a folder/directory.  It cant open inside a file.

Comment: You already should have `Run with PowerShell` or `Open with...`.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to right click open a powershell script (.ps1) file? If yes, that was disabled long time ago for security.

Comment: Ok, watched a tutorial about C++ where it looked like a file was opened directly in Developer Powershell for Visual Studio 2019, so assumed it was possible. Thanks for help, appreciate it :)  :)

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other posters. MS specifically disabled the ability to double-click to rn *.ps*, by directly associating those with NOtepad.exe. You can change that, ***but it is not advised, especially globally in an enterprise.***

If you are just trying to ***edit*** a file from a right click.

The Q&D (quick and dirty) option is just add a properly configured shortcut to your 'SendTo' menu and use that instead of 'Open With'. No registry hacking is required.

***As for Right-Click Open With and Right-Click Run With***

If you are trying to run a *.ps* from Windows Explorer right-click, then add this key.

If for example for example PWSH, then :

```
Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\PowerShell7x64\Command

C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -Command "$host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'PowerShell 7 (x64)'; if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process Bypass }; & '%1'"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind and informative answer  :)  :)

Comment: No worries... ;-}